# Android - How to efficiently change Bitmap dimensions

Tags: android, exception, memory, opengl-es, bitmap

I have an android application where I load resource image files and create textures for them so I can render them using OpenGL. However I am using mipmaps and the image dimensions must be powers of two. This is why I need to possibly increase the width or height of the given Bitmap before making the texture.

Here is my code that currently does the work:

```
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.context.getResources(), resourceId);

    Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(nextPowerOfTwo(bitmap.getWidth()), 
            nextPowerOfTwo(bitmap.getHeight()), bitmap.getConfig());

    int x=0,y=0,width=bitmap.getWidth(),height=bitmap.getHeight();
    int [] pixels = new int[width * height];
    bitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, x, y, width, height);
    newBitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, x, y, width, height);
    bitmap.recycle();
    gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, textureCount);
            ...
```

This worked perfectly on my Asus TF101 and Nexus 4 but I am getting an OutOfMemory exception for Galaxy S3 (and probably more devices), in the following line:

```
int [] pixels = new int[width * height];
```

From doing some reading I realized that the call to Bitmap.createBitmap is also memory expensive, and I am trying to think of a way to reduce the memory waste. 
First idea that comes to mind is using a smaller 2D array for 'int[] pixels' and copying fewer pixels at a time. But I am wondering if there is any other more efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

since you are just creating a scaled bitmap, this method should be the solution to your problem: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap, int, int, boolean)

```
Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, nextPowerOfTwo(bitmap.getWidth()), nextPowerOfTwo(bitmap.getHeight()), false);
bitmap.recycle();
```

Comment: This is not the best solution because Bitmap scaling (enlarging in this case) can hurt its quality. This is why I am simply currently adding empty space to the bitmap and then give openGL the texture coordinates that have my original image and the pixels stay at their place. Other constructors can only make create subsets of the bitmap. Is there another solution?